# Body content div expand To fill screen while maintaining footer

Tags: html, css

Hi there I've been doing research on the site for some time now and i haven't been able to find an answer that correct my problem. I'm looking to expand my body div to fill 100% while maintaining my footer at the bottom of my page. As you'll see in my code the footer is a bit problematic since I'm using a "Banner" and below the contact info for the site. (See provided image).Anyway I've tried some solutions found on other questions but i haven't been able to apply the solution to my code correctly. If someone could point me in the right direction id deeply appreciate it. Also id like to maintain the code with html and css only if at all possible.

[image: Web Layout, see this image]

The page should not be scrollable on regular sized displays as i have very little content 
to put on the website.Here i have provided a jsfiddle to further illustrate my problem. On it you'll see that what i want is my body(green) to dinamically change height to always fill the screen. taking into account that my footer(blue) should also be displayed on screen as well.

[My JSFiddle]http://jsfiddle.net/yuyocollores/3aJBP/2/

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Fri, 30 May 2014 18:35:33 GMT">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<title>Some Title</title>
<link href="gr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body id="htmlbody">
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/bigLOGO.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <img src="images/homeCONTENT.png" id="homecontent">
        <p id="hometext">
            Some Slogan text
        </p>

    </div>      
</div>
<div id="footerImageBanner">
          <img src="images/LogoVersion2Small.png" />
     </div>
    <div id="footercontainer">
                <p id="footertextsmall">
                    Address:
                    <span id="footertextsmall">Some address</span>
                </p>
                <p id="footertextsmall">
                    Copyright
                    <span id="footertextsmall">@2014</span>
                </p>
                <p id="footertextsmall">
                    Phone:
                    <span id="footertextsmall">(xxx)xxx-xxxx</span>
                </p>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my current CSS

```
#htmlbody{
 margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 background-color:#000000;
 }
#container
{
width: 100%;
min-width:500px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#header
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
min-width:500px;
height: 100px;
background-image: url('images/headerBG.png');
background-size: auto;
display: block;
}

#header img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
} 

#nav
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
min-width:500px;
height: 54px;
background-image: url('images/navbarBG.png');
background-repeat: repeat-x;
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#nav li
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
}

#nav a
{
margin: 0px;
padding-right:6px;
padding-left:-3px;
width: 114px;
height: 50px;
background-image: url('images/btn.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align:center;
color: #ffffff;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #333333;
}

#nav a:hover
{
background-image:url('images/btnHover.png'); 
}

#body
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
min-width:500px;
height:auto;
min-height:500px;
background-image: url('images/contentBG.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
overflow:auto;
}

#homecontent
{
width: 100%;
min-width:500px;
height: auto;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

#hometext
{
padding:0px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #cccccc;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;
font-size: 165%;
font: arial;
text-align: center;
}

#hometextsmall
{
color: #cc9966;
text-align: center;
font-size: x-large;
}
#contactcontent{
width:720px;
height:400px;
min-height:400px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-top:5px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color:#666666;
}
#pagecontent
{
width:550px;
height:450px;
min-height:450px;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-bottom:10px;
padding-top:5px;
border-radius: 15px;
background-color:#666666;
}
#pagecontent ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding-left:20px;
margin: 0px;
}

#pagecontent ul li {
background-image: url(images/bullet.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0px 5px; 
padding-left: 14px; 
}
#pagecontenttext{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #131010;
font: arial;
font-size:18px;
}

#contact{
float:left;
display:block;
width:350px;
height:400px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#footercontainer
{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height:auto;
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
background-image: url('images/footerBG.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
}

#footercontainer p
{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
vertical-align: top;
}


#footertextsmall
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size:small;
}

#footerImageBanner
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-image: url('images/footerImgBG.png');
background-size: auto;
display: block;
}

#footerImageBanner img
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: can u provide jsfiddle?

Comment: yes for a fiddle, about your image , where is the scrollbar suppose to appear when content is higher than room avalaible inside the window ?

Comment: Would appreciate if you create a fiddle at www.jsfiddle.com and ask specific question. You can expect a proper solution only if you ask a question properly.

Comment: Here I've provided a jsfiddle. Sorry for not bringing one earlier as I've never made one before. i added color to the elements to illustrate my problem.What i want to accomplish is to enlarge the body(green) so that it always fills the screen but taking in consideration my footer(Blue).Basically i want that bellow the Some Slogan Text be filled with nothing to fill the remainder of the screen accounting for the footer to be displayed.Also i dont want the page to scroll on regular size screen. Only scrollable if display screen is too small. As i have very little content to be displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yuyocollores/3aJBP/2/

Answer (score 0):

hey do you mean......

```
#container div{
 background-color:#fff;
 margin:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/QFN9U/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fiddle. I have never created one but your illustration serve me to get an example and make my own. Thanks